# Progressive web app install for second time

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I'm playing around with PWA and so far everything is very promising. However I can't find a way to show PWA install banner for second time. For example the user installs the app use it for some time and then uninstalls the app. If the user visits again the website the PWA banner will never appear unless you clean all local storage of Chrome. There is got to be a better way and more important user friendly. Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: The banner that is shown to prompt a user to install a PWA is displayed by the browser. The criteria that determines what causes the prompt to appear is quite nebulous right now, and not up to developers.

Answer (score -1):

Open "Developer Tools", select "Application" tab, choose "Manifest" on the left, Click on "Add to Homescreen" on the right.